# standardization of pandas dataframe groups/chunks (how to insert rows fast)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have "objects" (represented each by some rows in a table) which are described in multiple rows. But the problem is, that objects sometimes miss rows. My goal is to have a DataFrame where each object has the same amount of rows (same shape), where missing rows of an object are filled with empty rows.

For example:

**object 1**

```
O-ID | key 1 | key 2 | ... | key N  | value 1 | value 2 | value N
   0 | A 11  | A 21  | ... | key N1 |         |         | 
   0 | A 13  | A 23  | ... | key N3 |         |         | 
   0 | A 16  | A 26  | ... | key N6 |         |         |
```

**object 2**

```
 O-ID | key 1 | key 2 | ... | key N  | value 1 | value 2 | value N
    1 | A 12  | A 22  | ... | key N2 |         |         | 
    1 | A 13  | A 23  | ... | key N3 |         |         | 
    1 | A 14  | A 24  | ... | key N4 |         |         |
```

"O-ID" is the Object-ID. We can see that there are 6 different kinds of rows in total. In the end, I want each object to have all 6 rows. key 1 .. key-N are keys in sense of key-value pairs (with value 1 ... value N).

The result should look like this:

**object 1:**

```
O-ID | key 1 | key 2 | ... | key N  | value 1 | value 2 | value N
   0 | A 11  | A 21  | ... | key N1 |         |         | 
   0 | A 12  | A 22  | ... | key N2 | Null    | Null    | Null
   0 | A 13  | A 23  | ... | key N3 |         |         | 
   0 | A 14  | A 24  | ... | key N4 | Null    | Null    | Null
   0 | A 15  | A 25  | ... | key N5 | Null    | Null    | Null
   0 | A 16  | A 26  | ... | key N6 |         |         |
```

**object 2:**

```
O-ID | key 1 | key 2 | ... | key N  | value 1 | value 2 | value N
   1 | A 11  | A 21  | ... | key N1 | Null    | Null    | Null
   1 | A 12  | A 22  | ... | key N2 |         |         | 
   1 | A 13  | A 23  | ... | key N3 |         |         | 
   1 | A 14  | A 24  | ... | key N4 |         |         | 
   1 | A 15  | A 25  | ... | key N5 | Null    | Null    | Null
   1 | A 16  | A 26  | ... | key N6 | Null    | Null    | Null
```

I don't know how to do this besides using a slow for-loop...

Do you know a better/faster way to find out which rows are missing, and how to insert "Null"-rows?

I already had the idea of grouping them by "O-ID" and then using a map on the groups. But how do I insert the "null"-rows in the right order in a fast way?

I'm using the latest pandas version and the latest python 3

Comment: shouldn't there be a Null row for `key 1 == 'A 11'` in the result object 2?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed that. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create a [multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product) from all the keys we need in the result dataframe `res`. Then we [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) our dataframe with this new multiindex. In the last step we convert the key tuples back to individual columns and reorder the columns and sort the rows as needed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'O_ID': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2],
                    'key_1': ['A11', 'A13', 'A16', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'A15'],
                    'key_2': ['A21', 'A23', 'A26', 'A22', 'A23', 'A24', 'A25'],
                    'key_n': ['key N1', 'key N3', 'key N6', 'key N2', 'key N3', 'key N4', 'key N5'],
                    'value_1': [11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
                    'value_2': [21,22,23,24,25,26,27],
                    'value_n': [121,122,123,124,125,126,127]
                    })

keycols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('key')]
valcols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('value')]

# create multiindex of all combinations of O_ID and key tuples
keys = df[keycols].apply(tuple, axis=1)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.O_ID.unique(), keys.unique()], names=['O_ID','key_tuples'])

# set index of O_ID and key tuples and reindex with new multiindex
res = df.set_index(['O_ID',keys]).drop(columns=keycols)
res = res.reindex(idx).reset_index()

# split key tuples back into individual columns and reorder/sort as needed
res = pd.DataFrame(res.key_tuples.to_list(), index=res.index, columns=keycols).join(res).drop(columns=['key_tuples'])
res = res.reindex(columns=['O_ID']+keycols+valcols).sort_values(['O_ID']+keycols)
```

Result:

```
    O_ID key_1 key_2   key_n  value_1  value_2  value_n
0      0   A11   A21  key N1     11.0     21.0    121.0
3      0   A12   A22  key N2      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      0   A13   A23  key N3     12.0     22.0    122.0
4      0   A14   A24  key N4      NaN      NaN      NaN
5      0   A15   A25  key N5      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      0   A16   A26  key N6     13.0     23.0    123.0
6      1   A11   A21  key N1      NaN      NaN      NaN
9      1   A12   A22  key N2     14.0     24.0    124.0
7      1   A13   A23  key N3     15.0     25.0    125.0
10     1   A14   A24  key N4     16.0     26.0    126.0
11     1   A15   A25  key N5      NaN      NaN      NaN
8      1   A16   A26  key N6      NaN      NaN      NaN
12     2   A11   A21  key N1      NaN      NaN      NaN
15     2   A12   A22  key N2      NaN      NaN      NaN
13     2   A13   A23  key N3      NaN      NaN      NaN
16     2   A14   A24  key N4      NaN      NaN      NaN
17     2   A15   A25  key N5     17.0     27.0    127.0
14     2   A16   A26  key N6      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

(I had to add a third object with key A15, otherwise it is unclear from your sample data where this key should come from, i.e. this method uses all *existing* keys. If you know all the key values in advance and want to build the result dataframe with these keys, no matter if they occur in the input dataframe or not, then you can create your multiindex from these known key values instead of the unique keys present in the input data)